# [TFSTDERRLogOperation class]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, xcode, zombie-process

I just got this message in Xcode  : [TFSTDERRLogOperation class]: message sent to deallocated instance

I dont know where to search because search engines doesnt help so much about the TFSTDERRLogOperation class.

Comment: ok for the closed question... but hey, search in google , the only info about TFSTDERRLogOperation is this stackoverflow page, a bit strange isnt it ?  even if I use some external libs, docs are generally available online and It is very rare to get 0 infos about a class (which is not yours) on search engines, but thanks to phix23  for the info about testflight which is used in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TFSTDERRLogOperation` is a private class of the TestFlight SDK. Maybe this is a bug in the SDK. You can [report](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/emails/new) this to TestFlight support.

Comment: thanks for this info.now google knows about it with this page :)